# Trouble configuring a powerconnect 5548. Can't set to Master

Tags: networking, ip, command-line-interface, switch, dell

So I've inherit a powerconnect 5548P that I'm trying to setup but I can't get it to work.

When I first plugged it I remember it was assigned an IP and I was able to reach the web interface.

Now I'm trying to set the admin password via CLI but the problem I'm having is that there is no console prompt, only ">" and the only command I have are either debug or help. I can no longer reach the web UI either.

From what I understand the switch is stuck as a slave (instead of Master) in stacking mode. This would explain the "Master" LED being off and not having any console.Even setting the stack unit to 1 in the boot menu doesn't work.

[Here are the boot logs](http://pastebin.com/FeXUKBAP)

I've also downloaded and installed the newest firmware using XMODEM but still....

I know my serial cable and terminal are good because I configured a 2248 before.

I've tried a lot of things so far but nothing seems to work. How can I factory reset the switch or force it to be master ?

Any ideas ? I hope my switch is not bricked :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the unit was defective. Dell replaced it and the new one if working fine. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are at menu with only the `debug` and `help` menus, I believe your problem may be that the switch is not a master switch.   That is, it was part of a switch stack and it was not switch number 1, or the master switch.

I had a similar problem, but in my case because of the switch location (inaccessible physically), I could not use the physical reset switch.  Instead, if you have serial access to the console CLI, you can "unstack" by forcing the switch to be unit 1, or master.  Reload/reboot the switch and at the boot prompt quickly (within two seconds) press either `Return` or `ESC`.  Should look something like this:

```
Autoboot in 2 seconds - press RETURN or Esc. to abort and enter prom.
```

Once you abort the auto boot, you should see a menu like:

```
Startup Menu
[1]  Download Software
[2]  Erase Flash File
[3]  Password Recovery Procedure
[4]  Set Terminal Baud-Rate
[5]  Stack menu
[6]  Back
Enter your choice or press 'ESC' to exit:
```

Select `[5]  Stack menu`; then:

```
Stack menu
[1]  Show unit stack id
[2]  Set unit stack id
[3]  Back
Enter your choice or press 'ESC' to exit:
```

Look at the current stack id, option `[1]  Show unit stack id`; it should say something like:

```
Current working mode is stacking.
Unit stack id set to 3.
```

Note that it says something other than id "1".  Assuming something
different, then select `[2]  Set unit stack id`

```
Enter unit stack id [0-8]: 1

Unit stack id updated to 1.
```

Finally, use option `[3]  Back` and then `[6]  Back` to exit
back out of the menuing system and allow the unit to boot normally.
At this point it should prompt you with the setup wizard or at least
be back to a more expected prompt where you can update or reset or
change the unit's other configuration items.

Other helpful information can be found in the [Dell 5500 series manual](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/common/powerconnect-5500-series_ug_en-us.pdf), specifically page 48/49.

Answer (score 0):

Every powerconnect I've ever worked with has a hard reset somewhere on the switch.  This is one of those little pinholes that you need a straitened paperclip to press.

If it is stuck in a weird state, that shouldn't hurt.

The other option would be to drop into PROM mode and force a reset to factory from there.